# ¿Cómo retiro "Capítulo x" de mi texto en latex?

Tags: latex

He intentado retirar las dos palabras que aparecen antes del capítulo "Capítulo 01" pero no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo, si alguien supiera como hacerlo, lo agradecería bastante.

[image: Problema planteado]

El código empleado:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%espacios en el documento
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{ 
    a4paper,
    top = 2.5cm,
    bottom = 2.5cm,
    left = 2.5cm,
    right = 2.5cm,
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Probabilidades}

\section{primera}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa esta notación `\chapter*{Probabilidades}` para que no se añada título

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%espacios en el documento
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{ 
    a4paper,
    top = 2.5cm,
    bottom = 2.5cm,
    left = 2.5cm,
    right = 2.5cm,
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Probabilidades}

\section{primera}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Si queremos modificar el comportamiento del título de capítulo sin modificar el resultado en otras partes del documento, entonces hay es que cambiar la forma como el *header* del capítulo se genera

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    %    \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    %    \par\nobreak
    %    \vskip 20\p@
    %\fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
  \makeatother
```

Fuente de la segunda parte: [esta respuesta](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30537/95812)

Comment: El problema es que con eso, pierdo el titulo en el índice

Comment: @MonkeyD.Erick respuesta editada

Comment: ¡¡¡ Gracias !!!